# Scala import issue with PredictionIO Universal Recommender integration test

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender, predictionio

I've tried to get the Universal Recommender template set up as per the instructions located at [UR Quickstart](http://actionml.com/docs/ur_quickstart).  Getting an import error.  Is there a dependency/step that I missed?

```
[ERROR] [Engine$] [error] \import org.apache.mahout.math.cf.{DownsamplableCrossOccurrenceDataset, SimilarityAnalysis}
[ERROR] [Engine$] [error] ^
[ERROR] [Engine$] [error] one error found
```

The relevant block in my build.sbt file is as follows:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.predictionio" %% "apache-predictionio-core" % pioVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.predictionio" %% "apache-predictionio-data-elasticsearch1" % pioVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.4.0" % "provided",
"org.xerial.snappy" % "snappy-java" % "1.1.1.7",
// Mahout's Spark libs
"org.apache.mahout" %% "mahout-math-scala" % mahoutVersion,
"org.apache.mahout" %% "mahout-spark" % mahoutVersion
exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-core_2.10"),
"org.apache.mahout"  % "mahout-math" % mahoutVersion,
"org.apache.mahout"  % "mahout-hdfs" % mahoutVersion
exclude("com.thoughtworks.xstream", "xstream")
exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-client"),
//"org.apache.hbase"        % "hbase-client"   % "0.98.5-hadoop2" % 
"provided",
```

Comment: A fix is already pushed, my fumble fingers :-(

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard.  I'm not familiar with scala syntax so I didn't realize the incorrect inclusion of the backslash in the source file was problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this answer as an alternative for build PIO-UR engine.

Actually, I also had struggled with these dependency issues. What I am telling you is not the right solution for this. But this will provide you a working PredictionIO UR engine.

Use the docker image for the universal recommender template.
[Use this link for getting PIO-UR docker image.](https://github.com/gozutok/docker-universalrecommender)

If you are not familiar with docker, use these links below :

INSTALLATIONS:

1. [Docker for MAC](https://www.docker.com/docker-mac)
2. [Docker for Windows](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows)
3. For Ubuntu, use automated script: curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh

Then use the above image from git for using the UR template. By using docker, we don't need to struggle with the dependencies. The readme file in the git repository is really helpful and use that as a guide. You can set the PIO engine up and run with 3 simple commands.